# pyodbc (4.0.23) error connecting to MySQL from Python3

Tags: python, pyodbc

I tried to connect mysql via pyodbc, same code works on python2, but I get an error on python3.

here is my code:

```
_protocal = 'DRIVER={/usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5.so};SERVER=127.0.0.1; 
PORT=3306;DATABASE=learn;UID=root;PASSWORD=root'
conn = pyodbc.connect(_protocal)
cursor = conn.cursor()
test_sql = 'select * from students'
cursor.execute(test_sql)
```

here is the error message on python3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temp.py", line 82, in <module>
    main()
  File "temp.py", line 71, in main
    cursor.execute(test_sql)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 5.1 Driver][mysqld- 
5.7.18]Querywas empty (1065) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: The last revision of MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 was released over five (5) years ago. I am unable to reproduce your issue using the latest GA version (currently 5.3.10). Try upgrading to the latest version of MySQL Connector/ODBC and see if that helps.

Comment: @GordThompson I updated odbc to 5.3.10, and updated iodbc to 3.52, python3 is worked. So you can copy your comment to answer, I will accept it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last revision of MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.1 was released over five (5) years ago.  Upgrading the driver to the latest GA version (5.3.10) and upgrading iODBC appears to have resolved the issue.